# iOS16.1 Updated BLE Connection Interval from iOS16.0?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, disconnect, ios16

When Apple officially released iOS16.0 to users, our custom device that uses a nRF52832 Nordic based BLE chip would no longer hold the connection for more that 90 seconds before disconnecting. We realized that with iOS16.0, Apple changed their requested Connection Intervals and we had to modify them on our product to solve.

However, when we updated to iOS16.1 this month, our original Connection Intervals on our product are working again. **Does anyone know what Apple changed for iOS16.1 for the connection intervals? Why does iOS16.1 accept 7.5-15ms intervals when iOS16.0 doesn't?** There are no changes to the connection interval requirements on the Apple Design Guidelines as of the last revision Oct26th,2022.

Would really appreciate it if anyone can share more info on the BLE change logs for iOS16.1.

Thanks for the help!

For easy comparison, below are the connection intervals that we used in our product with iOS16.

- **[Previously Worked with iOS15 & below]** Connection Interval for Product: Min 7.5ms - Max 15ms

  - **Does not work with iOS16.0**
  - Does work with iOS16.1 & iOS16.1.1
- **[Had to Change for iOS16.0, 16.0.1, 16.0.2, 16.0.3]** Connection Interval for Product: Min 15ms - Max 30ms

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple don't usually publish all the details about their changelogs and bug fixes from one version to another. In your case, I believe I saw similar posts and it was due to Apple not allowing a Min connection interval of 7.5ms, due to the restrictions in the [Accessory Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/accessories/Accessory-Design-Guidelines.pdf) (sesction 41.6, Connection Parameters):-

The connection parameter request **may be rejected** if it does not meet the following guidelines:

- Peripheral Latency of up to 30 connection intervals.
- Supervision Timeout from 2 seconds to 6 seconds.
- **Interval Min of at least 15 ms.**
- Interval Min is a multiple of 15 ms.
- One of the following:

  - Interval Max at least 15 ms greater than Interval Min.
  - Interval Max and Interval Min both set to 15 ms.
- Interval Max * (Peripheral Latency + 1) of 2 seconds or less.
- Supervision Timeout greater than Interval Max * (Peripheral Latency + 1) * 3.

As you can see, given that they used the term "may be rejected" instead of "will be rejected", this means there's some leniency which is why maybe things worked for all versions apart from 16.0.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, thats what I have heard - that Apple is pretty bad at documenting changes from OS versions. 


I'm trying to figure out whether Apple will revert back to strictly following their CoreBluetooth protocols for the connection intervals in later updates of iOS16.1. Since we have hardware & customers that are affected, I'd like to know that I don't have to worry about it reverting back to not accepting 7.5-15ms until iOS17.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way of knowing unless if Apple confirm this themselves. I would recommend asking the question on Apple developer forum but I can see that you have done this already. If you have direct contact with any of the Apple engineers then this is your next bet.

Comment: The Guidelines release R21 from 2023-10-10 specify "Supervision Timeout from 6 seconds to 18 seconds" and "Interval Max * (Peripheral Latency + 1) of 2 seconds or less".  I don't know what iOS release this corresponds to.  At least iOS 16.7.1 is rejecting parameters that should be within the R21 guidelines.